# Rails 5 update enum not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In Rails and ActiveRecord, I am struggling with the behaviour of an `enum` I have in my model. First of all, the `default` that I set on the database level in the AR migration is not taking effect when I run tests and secondly, I cannot update it at all. Here is some code, simplified for the sake of brevity.

In my model, the enum is declared as follows:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  # as you can see this is a join table for different_model and another_model
  belongs_to :different_model
  belongs_to :another_model

  enum blocked: %w[no yes] # also tried with symbols, like: %i[no yes]
end
```

and the migration was as follows:

```rb
class AddBlockedToMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :my_models, :blocked, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

I create the object using:

```rb
my_model = MyModel.where(different_model: @different_model, another_model: @another_model).first_or_create
```

this works, I used `byebug` to check that this record is persisted and it is (therefore also valid)

and then try to update the enum `blocked` on it:

```rb
my_model.update(blocked: 'yes')
```

but the `blocked` attribute remains as `nil`.

I refactored, tried to use:

```rb
my_model.blocked = 'yes'
my_model.save
```

and stuck `byebug` in the middle to see if it was invalid somehow, it wasn't. `.valid?` returns `true` after changing `blocked` to `'yes'`, so I also tried changing it to an integer `1`, after save, it still returned to `nil`.

This problem only happens when running the test. When running in `rails console` everything works as I expect - the `default` in the database level takes over and instantiates the model with `blocked: 'no'` and it can also be updated in any *usual* AR way, just not in the test. Am I missing something really obvious here, or is it some strange side effect of `enum` that I'm not getting?

DB is Postgres, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: why don't you just use boolean true/false value for blocked instead of enum? Also as for enums it's a good practice to use them in Hash style, like `enum blocked: { no: 0, yes: 1 }`

Comment: thanks for the comment @nuaky, I considered this initially, but have read that booleans can be problematic with changing requirements. this attribute is obtained through a 3rd party API and I just figured that at some point the requirements may change on it. however, it's not worth wasting too much time over, so I may go with a boolean for now and consider a refactor if/when the time comes. thanks for the note about hashes though, duly noted!

Comment: Did you run `rake db:test:prepare` ? In general it is not needed, but if you changed a migration manually, rails cannot deduce the test database has to be re-initialised.

Comment: You can also update it through: `my_model.update(blocked: my_model.blocked[:yes]'`

Comment: You're absolutely right about booleans being problematic with changing requirements. You often see people creating nullable three-state Booleans columns which is a big no-no as boolean logic breaks down or adding tons of potentially conflicting switches to an object.

Comment: thanks to those who commented, very useful information all round!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Try to avoid `yes` and `no` as the enum values. Rails will create methods for each value, such as `#yes?`, `#no!`, and in case you'd need to add another yes/no enum for a different field, it might not work as you expect it.

Better define it like

```
enum status: [:released, :blocked]
```

or I actually prefer a hash representation to be explicit about what DB values are stored:

```
enum status: {
  released: 0,
  blocked: 1
}
```

then, instead of calling `update!`, just call

```
your_instance.blocked!
```

and it'll do the thing.

2) As a general advice, make this field not-nullable(as I assume you don't want this field to have three states at this moment) in database:

```
change_column_null :table_name, :column_name, true
```

Comment: Using a hash and declaring the enums explicitly is a good idea since just reordering the array will break things horribly if the mapping is implicit.

Comment: thanks for this, it worked nicely. also potentially useful note for anyone finding this is alongside the `blocked!` method to change the status to `blocked`, I found in the docs a `blocked?` method (returning a boolean, as is convention) to check whether the status is `blocked`. came in handy for my tests. it was also alluded to in the answer, but is easily missed.